# localStorage.getItem, localStorage.setItem functions don't work in Chrome extension ported to Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have developed Chrome extension.

In this extension, I used `localStorage.getItem`, `localStorage.setItem` functions to save some data.

After that, I converted Chrome extension to Firefox add-on.
In this case, I couldn't set, get some data into `localStorage`:

```
localStorage.getItem("data"); //it returns NULL
```

I hope that i will get solution here.
Thanks

Comment: Firefox has a bug which makes it clear DOM storage (HTML5 storage) inside extensions just like for web pages when the browser is set to `never remember history` or when `dom.storage.enabled` is false in about:config. It's unclear when this bug will be fixed, if ever, so you'll have to save the data in chrome.storage.local or chrome.storage.sync.

Comment: @wOxxOm.
I used `chrome.storage.local.get` and `chrome.storage.local.set` functions
It works well.
Thanks for your help